# Salesforce Communities - Napili Template

Tags: community, authentication, login, napili

I am setting up a new Napili Community - and I'm trying to figure out how to have both public (guest Users) and Private (authenticated, Self-registered users) working together on the site. I have enabled Self-Registration and it's working.

I understand there are 2 profiles (one for guest access & one for authenticated access) .

What I can't figure out is how to trigger the login page when a user goes from public content to authenticated content - shouldn't all Public Users - automatically get sent to a login or self-registration page?

I don't think this is possible. It appears that a site is either all Public or all private - but not both. This doesn't seem right - any ideas?

Comment: Think in terms of what permissions you allow for each profile. If a profile doesn't have access to an object, a user with that profile can't see those records. Remember that you can clone a profile to create a custom version of it with additional permissions. Also, be looking at your community license profiles, not your sites license profiles.

Comment: Hi, yes I realize this - the guest user profile does not have access but the registered user does have access - the problem is when a guest user clicks a link to access content that is available to registered users profile - it should automatically route the guest user to the sites login page to register - and it doesn't - this is 101 behavior with websites - the only thing that happens is a silly little error saying you don't have access - any ideas ?

Comment: Even registered users won't always have permission to access all records, for that reason, you wouldn't want an automatic redirect for all users when this occurs. If anything, you *might* perhaps want this behavior by profile for certain objects. To me, preferable behavior would be to ask users with that profile if they'd like to register and provide them with a link to do that. This would require a custom error message for that.

Comment: But I do want an automatic redirect for unregistered users just like 99% of authenticated websites work - it's common - very common - it just doesn't look like the new Napili solution is ready for prime time

Comment: Hey @Kevin I'm having a similar problem still and I'm no closer than you seem to be on figuring this out. If I set the entire site to private, I can't even use a custom login screen anymore because the custom login is behind a private page, creating an infinite sign-on loop. I'd love to turn off the setting that makes the site fully private, but doing that exposes too much data to our non-registered users. Did you ever get any closer to solving this?

Answer (score 1):

You can set individual community pages public and keep other pages private. And if guest user try to access private pages they will be redirected to login page you setup for community site.

Answer (score 0):

While this doesn't solve your issue, I discovered there are a great number of Ideas in the Success Community related to your issue that you may want to vote up. I found them when I searched on "redirect". The first one seems the most relevant, but there are many more that seemed related:

- [Redirect Self-Service Portal users back to login page.](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000YnBcAAK)
- [Visualforce support for session scoped data](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000Bqr1AAC)
- [Fix broken timeout warning for Community users returning 404](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000BrYUAA0)
- [Time out on Self Service Portal](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000BrYUAA0)
- [Login flow in a full branded community](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000Dk8hAAC)
- [Logging out of Communities: Require "retURL" parameter to be a whitelisted URL](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000DwJ3AAK)
- [Add support for Site.logout()](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000kkYeAAI)
- [Conditional Action/Button Overrides based on License](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000YUtvAAG)
- [Need ability to send a direct link to article for Force.com Site portal users](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000kr75AAA)

Answer (score 0):

You could create a lightning component that does this and drop it on the pages where you need this functionality. It would have no markup, but in the init handler, it would check the logged in user's profile and redirect them to the login screen if they have the guest user (public) profile.